# Task reservation

Tags: camera

Could anyone let me know how I can reserve a task with python code? I'd make the Raspberry Pi take pictures with picamera at 2:00 am. But I want to make it automatically. How could I make it?

Comment: Google for Linux cron jobs.

Comment: Well, two or three points. The title is a little misleading and this question is not really pi specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joan already suggested `cron` will help you do that.

1. Write your python code as usual, save the script, make it executable and test it
2. Set up `cron` by using `sudo crontab -e`

Format and syntax of the crontab a very, very, very well documented both in the internet and the `man` page (try `man cron`). So I will just give a very short example here. There is many more to `cron` however - just look that up in the web.

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
0        2          *             *                *            /opt/your-path/your-script.py
```

Thus runs your script at 02:00AM each day. Be sure to add the full path to your script to be run properly. Also note that commands run by `cron` have no way to output anything that is piped to stdout or stderr. So you might want to output to files or use redirection (that means if your script contains a `print` statement you'll not see the result if the script is run via `cron`).

Be advised that `crontab -e` invokes the standard editor that is set in the environment ($EDITOR) so you might end up with a default editor that might be a "little complicated" to use as a beginner. In this case use `export EDITOR=nano` before `crontab -e` (assuming `nano` is installed).